# How to find the length of the JSON in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dropdown

I'm using API as a backed which returns a JSON file. I need to use this JSON data for a dropdown button in flutter the JSON data That I recieved is here.

```
[
    {
        "store": "AMAZON"
    },
    {
        "store": "FLIPKART"
    },
    {
        "store": "WALMART"
    },
    {
        "store": "ALIBABA"
    },

]
```

The length of the JSON may vary time to time.

In Flutter I decode this JSON with this line.

```
stores = json.decode(response.body);
print(stores[0]['store']);
```

I need to know the length of the json to use those data in dropdown button. If there is someother way to use json directly to dropdown also suggest me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783925/flutter-how-to-get-json-result-length

Might this help.

Comment: @GokulaKrishnan Sorry, I already searched it but it doesn't provide result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the length of json like this:

```
stores = json.decode(response.body);
final length = stores.length;
```

And get the list of items to use in a drop down widget:

```
  List<String> items = [];
  stores.forEach((s)=> items.add(s["store"]));

  new DropdownButton<String>(
  items: items.map((String value) {
    return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: new Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (_) {},
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always find the length of a JSON object by passing it through the map,

```
stores = json.decode(response.body);
(stores as Map<String, dynamic>).length
```

let me know this works or not.

Answer (score 0):

After decoding your json into stores, your stores is a list of json objects, so now you can simply get the length of the stores like this.

```
stores = json.decode(response.body);
int len = stores.length;
print('length = $len');
```